# Google Map Marker Manager V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

i've tried using google maps marker manager, but i seem to be hitting a brick wall everytime, i follow the tutorials on how to create markermanager on google documentation, but it seems nothing is working for me, is it a problem in how my code is written? running out of ideas here, at the moment i have set ONE marker to drop down on the map based on latlng.

can someone please try like implementing the tutorial code and find a working solution for me? its driving me mad.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:500px;"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    @*<script src="../../Scripts/markermanager.js" type="text/javascript"></script>*@

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // map view, can be set to satellite, street, roadview, aerialview
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                title: "Uluru (Ayers Rock)"
            });

            marker.setMap(map);  
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            initialize();
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: You've included the file but you're not using the marker manager class the the above code. Why is that?

Comment: brings up errors: GBounds is not defined
[Break On This Error] GBounds.prototype.containsPoint = function (point) { inside the markermanager.js file

Comment: What marker manager are you using? Are you using a marker manager that was made for GMAP API v2 with GMAP API v3?

Comment: right just put in the marker manager for v3, google dont make things simple, right im going to give it a go and create markers now using v3 and see how i get on.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is an example to get you started:

```js
var map;
var mgr;

function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  mgr = new MarkerManager(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(mgr, "loaded", function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(Math.random() * 180 - 90, Math.random() * 360 - 180),
        title: "Random marker #" + i
      });
      mgr.addMarker(marker, 0);
    }
    mgr.refresh();
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/src/markermanager.js"></script>

<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 400px;"></div>
<p>Pan or zoom out to see markers</p>
```

Notice that when creating a marker, I did not specify `map: map` or `marker.setMap(map)`. Instead, the markers are added to the marker manager which in turn adds them to the map when you call `markermanager.refresh()`.

Also note that I've added all markers on the zoom level `0`. Ideally you should load few markers on lower zoom levels and more markers on higher zoom levels.

- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/6nN7U/)
- [Marker Manager Reference](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/docs/reference.html)
- [Marker Manager Examples](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/docs/examples.html)

Comment: excellent example.. just what i needed, so i see we have used a for loop which will create up to 1000 markers and place them randomly using the math.random(), how would i get it so when the map loads up all markers are shown without zooming in or out to see them all?

will it be like: map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

Comment: for the example above how would i fit all markers on map without zooming in/out?

map.fitBounds(); is it like that?

Comment: working for me now, now i'll be looking at JSON Result in MVC3 :)

thanks Salman :)

Comment: Now that you mentioned JSON and Marker Manager, have a look at [this page](http://goo.gl/cKZnp) (uses api v2). Zoom the map out 5-6 times and pan the map; you'll notice the AJAX requests. Feel free to view-source.

Comment: how do i get an image url from my JSON on the google maps so when user clicks marker it displays image in the small popup window?

Comment: I believe you can easily do this via [infoWindows](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#InfoWindows). Check out the examples on that page.